# How to return objects with a specified length of letters from array?

Tags: javascript

The question is to return names with 4 characters from a string of names.

This is my code so far:

```js
var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry";
var newFriends = friends.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < newFriends.length; i++) {
  if (newFriends[i].length == 4) {
    console.log(newFriends[i]);
  }
}
```

The problem is the code just returns "Ryan" when it should return both Ryan and Luke, all of the names with 4 letters.

Comment: " Luck" is 5 in length because it has a leading space. Try this: `var newFriends = friends.split(/,\s*/);` Or just `var arr = friends.split(/,\s*/).filter(f => f.length == 4)`

Comment: `Kat` is logged too because it has 3 plus the space. Its log being below `Ryan` makes it clearer that there's a leading space.

Comment: @Shirley Hey, I know it has been a while, but the community would appreciate it if you accepted an answer :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods instead of a for-loop here.

Also, don't forget to include a trailing space inside your `split` token, otherwise each `length` will be recorded as one character more than it actually is.

```js
var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry"

var newFriends = friends.split(", ").filter(function (name) {
  return name.length === 4
}).join(", ")

console.log(newFriends)
```

Comment: `e.trim()` to remove white space, your answer has a bug :)

Comment: @Dummy he is splitting by `", "`. He doesn't need to trim the strings. :)

Answer (score 2):

While splitting your `string` you are including the whitespace between comma and the word. You can use `Array#map` with `String#trim` function to delete the unwanted whitespace and get the proper result.

```js
var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry",
    newFriends = friends.split(",").map(v => v.trim());

for (var i = 0; i < newFriends.length; i++) {
  if (newFriends[i].length == 4) {
    console.log(newFriends[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex that matches any character that isn't a space or a comma, and then limit that to four characters in the regex, and return the trimmed names to an array, that way it doesn't matter how many spaces you have between each name etc.

```js
var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry";
var newFriends = friends.match(/\b[^,\s]{4}\b/g);

console.log(newFriends)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because of the space you have after commas. Just trim the word as it to ignore those spaces while comparing.

```
var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry";
var newFriends = friends.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < newFriends.length; i++) {
  if (newFriends[i].trim().length == 4) {
    console.log(newFriends[i].trim()); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make it split by comma with a space, `friends.split(", ")`

```
var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry";
var newFriends = friends.split(", ");
for (var i = 0; i < newFriends.length; i++) {
  if (newFriends[i].length == 4) {
    console.log(newFriends[i]); 
  }
}
```

or trim the white spaces on both sides after the split,

```
var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry";
var newFriends = friends.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < newFriends.length; i++) {
  if (newFriends[i].trim().length == 4) {
    console.log(newFriends[i]); 
  }
}
```

or you could also use the map function to return an array of trimmed values,

```
var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry";
var newFriends = friends.split(",").map(function (val) { return val.trim(); });
for (var i = 0; i < newFriends.length; i++) {
  if (newFriends[i].length == 4) {
    console.log(newFriends[i]); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spacing is causing the problem. Instead, try:

```
var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry";
var newFriends = friends.split(", "); //And so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace spaces with empty string.

`var friends = "Ryan, Kat, Luke, Harry";
var newFriends = friends.replace(/\s*/g, "").split(",");
....`